# SSDT SSIS Execution Results window display corrupt

Tags: ssis

I'm Using Visual Studio Community 15.9.3 with SSDT

Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 15.0.900.40

I'm on a dell xps with 3840 x 2160 resolution.

When I execute a package the Execution Results tab displays with half of each line missing.

See below

[image]

I'm tried maximising the design window but this has no effect.  I've repaired SSDT and this has no effect.  I've uninstalled it and then re-installed but this has no effect.

Any ideas of any other steps I can take?

Comment: Your font does't look like the default. Check "Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors". My default fonts are all Consolas 10pt.

Comment: Lists Consolas 10pt  I'm uninstalling VS/SSDT and will re-install

Comment: My guess is that the OS is applying a scaling factor to all fonts. It's pretty common on laptops with higher resolutions like yours. You might check your Display settings (right-click on the Desktop and go to Display) to make sure scaling is set at 100%.